# there is only one method that cannot be called from another project

Tags: c#, methods, project, call

Although I found some similar questions here, I didn't find an answer that would help me solve my problem.
I have one solution (C#) with 2 projects: P1 (Class Library) and P2 (Console application). I did add a reference in P2, and also using statement in P2, and all the classes are public (in both projects). But, while I was writing a method in P2, I needed to call a method from a class in P1, but actually couldn't do it. All the other methods from any of the classes in P1 I could call, except for this one. What could be a problem?

Here is the class in P1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace P1
{
    public class Song
    {
        private string name;
        private double length;

        public double Length { get { return length; } set { length = value; } }

        public Song(string name, double length)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.length = length;
        }

        public  Song ReadSong()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Song name: ");
            string songName = Console.ReadLine();

            bool wrongEntry = true;
            double songLength = 0;
            while (wrongEntry)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Song length: ");
                string songLengthStr = Console.ReadLine();
                try
                {
                    songLength = Double.Parse(songLengthStr);
                    wrongEntry = false;
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
                }
            }
            return new Song(songName, songLength);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the class in P2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using P1;

namespace P2
{
    public class Festival
    {

        private string name;
        private List<Artist> listOfArtists;

        public Festival(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            listOfArtists = new List<Artist>();
        }

        public Artist ReadArtst()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Artist name: ");
            string artName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Date of birth: ");
            DateTime dat = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Artist art = new Artist(artName, dat);

            Console.WriteLine("How many songs do you want to enter: ");
            int number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {

            }
            return art;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }     

    }
}
```

In the class Festival (which is in the second project) in the for loop I need to call ReadSong() (from the Song class which is the first project), but for some reason it cannot be called. I also tried to use some other method that I have (public void AddSong(Song newSong), which is implemented in Artist class, and it works). ReadSong() is the only method that I cannot call in for loop.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing any code. Try to clean and rebuild.

Comment: My best guess would be somewhere an `interface` is involved.

Comment: Sometimes this is caused by the dependent project not referencing the needed assemblies.  Is the P2 project targeting "Client Framework", by any chance?

Comment: Clean and rebuild is not helping. I am not using interface here. And no, it's not targeting Client Framework.

Comment: Show some code. Without code, we're pretty much left to guessing. For all we know, you're trying to call it with the wrong method signature.  Without code, we have no way to know if it's some obscure 'feature' of c#, or a simple typo on your part.

Comment: There, I posted some code.

Comment: How are you attempting to call `ReadSong`? Like `Song.ReadSong`? Or are you creating an instance of the `Song` class and calling the method on that? It's not clear from your code.

Comment: Maybe something like: art.AddSong(ReadSong()); or: art.ListOfSongs.Add(ReadSong()); where ListOfSongs is alist in Artist.cs.  I know it's not really clear for you because you don't have the whole solution. Btw. Would it be ok if I made the ReadSong() method STATIC and then in for loop called it like: Song.ReadSong(); ?

Comment: Ah, that's your answer - you're trying to call it without an instance of the class.
Because `ReadSong` relies on instance variables (`name` and `length`) I wouldn't think it could be static.
You need to create an instance of the `Song` class and then call `ReadSong` on it.
You might want to read up on C# classes and methods to get a clearer understanding.

Comment: I am not sure if the answer is to create an instance of the Song in ReadArtist(). I think it could be better to make Song static. Someone correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, you say you're trying to call `ReadSong` like this:

```
art.AddSong(ReadSong());
```

or

```
art.ListOfSongs.Add(ReadSong());
```

But that doesn't work because `ReadSong` is a method of the `Song` class.

You'll need to instantiate the class first to call the method on it, e.g.:

```
Song song = new Song(name, length);
song.ReadSong();
```

But you have deeper problems in your code - your `ReadSong` method creates a new instance of the `Song` class when you call it. As I'm not sure about exactly what you're trying to achieve, I can only suggest that you take some time to either re-think your design, or do some reading on C# to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it like that, but it's not possible. How can I instantiate it in ReadArtist() method where I don't have either name or length of the song (because in ReadArtist() I am trying to read artist from keyboard, not song)? That's why I wonder if I can make ReadSong() static, so I would not need an instance. Thanks for help, I know it's not easy when there are only parts of code that you can see.

Comment: Think of it like this - is there one universal Song, or many different songs? Can an artist have a collection of many songs?
The problem is with your logic - go back to the design phase, because right now you don't know where or how to create the song.
Does an artist always have the same list of songs? When you create an artist, how do you know what songs they have? Does the list of songs for an artist come from a database, from user input or are they hard coded?
Take some time to think about the relationship between the objects in your application.